# Size of the .exe file made using CMake is too large

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, cross-platform, release

I was making a `C++`-program using `Visual Studio`. The size of the executable was `490 KB`.

But when I make the same executable by creating `CMake Project` in `Visual Studio`, the size of the executable is `1140 KB`.

Why is it so big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that CMake was running the `RelWithDebInfo` build.

`set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)` solved my problem. Size of executable was reduced to `483 KB`.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the executable file depends on the optimizations used and the symbols preserved in the executable file.

Usually, the build mode has the most impact on the size. By default, `CMake` typically has settings for each type of build, but you can customize them yourself by conditioning on the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable.

For example:

```
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    target_compile_options(<executable> PRIVATE -Wall -O0 -g3)
endif()
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
    target_compile_options(<executable> PRIVATE -O3 -flto -s -Wl,-s -Wl,--gc-sections)
endif()
```

If you want to minimize the executable file size as much as possible, I recommend using the `MinSizeRel` mode. Like that:

```
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "MinSizeRel")
    target_compile_options(<executable> PRIVATE -Os -flto -s -Wl,-s -Wl,--gc-sections)
endif()
```

Additionally, after the build, you can use utilities such as `strip` and `upx`.
To add their execution after the build, you need to write the following code:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET <executable> POST_BUILD
        COMMAND strip -s <path-to-executable>)
add_custom_command(TARGET <executable> POST_BUILD
        COMMAND upx -qqq --best <path-to-executable>
        # This might break the the executable:
#        COMMAND upx -qqq --best --ultra-brute --overlay=strip <path-to-executable>
)
```

Note that `upx` tool compresses the executable, so loading it into memory will take longer than usual.